# Is it possible that fire produces only invisible light?

Tags: energy, visible-light, thermal-radiation

I was just wondering that is it ever possible that some object produces **only** invisible light when it catches fire? Something like invisible flames.

If this is possible, can you please give one example?

I have checked a phenomenon called [Back-body Radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation) and energy emitted by excited electron when fall back to lower orbit, which are responsible for colour of the flame. It looks like it is possible to produce invisible flames.

Please correct me if I am wrong on any point.

Comment: Certainly.  I would guess that most of the radiation from a flame is invisible.  (Not *light* because light is always visible, by definition.)

Comment: Burning pure  hydrogen in oxygen produces very little visible light - it is mostly in the UV.

Comment: Searching for invisible combustion also comes up with a few results, such as methanol fires.

Comment: What is your definition of invisible?  Due to black body radiation, all matter produces radiation at all wavelengths at all times.  However, that radiation in the visible spectrum may be quite faint compared to the other nearby sources of light, making this a signal-to-noise-ratio problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fire that is most difficult to see is [Hydrogen burning in air](https://spinoff.nasa.gov/spinoff1997/ps1.html), which is does with a pale blue flame making it almost invisible in daylight. [Methanol is similar in some ways as well](http://blackflag.jalopnik.com/this-bizarre-video-explains-why-people-tend-to-avoid-us-1682531752).

Answer (score 0):

Flame that you can see is light. Light is just small part of all the electromagnetic waves that your eye can detect. There is wide range of electromagnetic frequencies that are not visible to naked eye. [Here you can read about it more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation#Electromagnetic_spectrum).

The answer is yes there are invisible electromagnetic waves when stuff burns ([like infrared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cool_flame)).

Comment: But is there also a process in which a material 'burns' without producing radiation in the visible spectrum? I suppose then one needs to define what it is to burn, which is not very robust. Wikipedia writes that combustion is a high-temperature exothermic redox chemical reaction between a fuel and an oxidant, which is a start I suppose.

Comment: Anything rusting is a low temperature fire that is only emitting infrared

Comment: @MartinBeckett:   Yes, it is oxidation, but to be called fire, doesn't it need to give off excess heat, which then increases the reaction rate for the nearby atoms/molecules?   In the case of iron rusting, the rate is so low, that the local oxidation doesn't increase the rate of other local oxidation.   It is all conducted, convected or radiated away because the time scales are so disjoint.   No chain reaction = not fire.

Comment: @user129412 rusting is technically slow burning so you're absolutely correct on this.